# convert python numpy log array expression to cpp xtensor

Tags: python, c++, pandas, numpy, xtensor

I'm trying to convert NumPy/python code to CPP/xtensor.
I have difficulty converting the following statement.

```
data = pd.read_csv(input_file,sep=',')
v = data.values
x = v[1:]/v[:-1]
LX1 = np.log(x[t-(2*w) + 1:t - w + 1,:]) <=== how do I write this in cpp
```

How would I write this in xtensor?

Answer (score 0):

Slicing in xtensor can be done with [views](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/view.html).

In python:

```py
x[t-(2*w) + 1:t - w + 1,:]
```

In c++, with xtensor:

```cpp
xt::view(x, xt::range(t - (2*w) + 1, t - w + 1), xt::all());
```

Logs in xtensor can be performed with `xt::log()`

You can also check conversions from numpy to xtensor in the [From numpy to xtensor](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html) section.